# Get Instance of WebTarget in OSGi

Tags: java, maven, osgi, jersey-2.0

I am running some tests n OSGi and trying to create an instance of `WebTarget` to test the endpoints published in OSGi with the following code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
...
...

private static final String port = "8080";
private static final String CONTEXT = "/someContext";
private static final URI baseUri = URI.create("http://localhost:" + port + CONTEXT);

@Test
public void sentence() {
    Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    final WebTarget target = c.target(baseUri);

    Response response = target.path("/service").request().post(Entity.entity(new MockMessage("123", "sessionId123"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE), Response.class);

    logger.info("JERSEY RESULT = " + response.toString());
    assertEquals(Response.ok().build(), response);
}
```

The problem is that when it runs it then throws the exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No generator was provided and there is no default generator registered`. And it comes worst because the missing class (`RuntimeDelegateImpl`) is under the *internal* package of the `jersey-common-2.x.jar` bundle.

So, has anyone an idea on how to create an instance of a `WebTarget` under OSGi?

BTW, I already have these two dependencies in the pom file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What is `WebTarget` anyway? What package or library does it belong to? You have omitted your imports in the code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am using Arquillian to run the tests under OSGi, then I finally solved it by adding the annotation `@RunAsClient` to run the test outside the OSGi container and avoid dependencies not found in the `.internal` package.